# Run Skrollr In IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, skrollr

I am attempting to run some very simple Skrollr animations in an IFrame. When I populate the IFrame with the simple HTML Skrollr outputs the error to the console (in FireFox):

'Not well formed'

I have confirmed that the IFrame contents are correct and run just fine if they are not in an iframe and in a standard webpage. And I've confirmed that the Skrollr javascript file/s are loading successfully. All CSS, JS and images are all on the same domain as the parent webpage so there's no cross-domain occurring. The problem exhibits itself when the content is placed in an IFrame. Which makes me think this is a Cross-Scripting issue or that Skrollr is coded to detect cross-domain/cross-scripting?

Any idea's whats going wrong and how I can overcome this? I can provide a simple example if you wish. Hoping to grab Prinzhorn's attention, yes I know Skrollr's not currently maintained and that IFrame's are not officially supported but if I have an idea of whats going wrong or what the problem is I can fork Skrollr and add this functionality.

**Edit**: Heres a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vuqLzw8e/) example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tasks</title>
    <style>

        #main-container {
                width            : 1200px;
                height           : 1000px;
                background-color : #eee;
        }

        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: scroll;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container text-center">

        <button id="load-btn">Load Iframe</button>

        <br/>

        <div id="main-container" class="text-center">
            <iframe id="mf-preview" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Javascript files -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Since you offered, a simple code example would be great, thanks! That's kind of what we're all about here :) Stack snippet or JSFiddle preferred!

Answer (score 0):

everything is working brother

when the size of your iframe is more then 1000px then it will show the scroll bar

Like example :

```
<iframe id="mf-preview" src="http://onhax.net" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I have add the source of iframe which is larger then 1200px
and after add this like it will show the scroll bar

check it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nn372e8/)

Comment: thanks for your answer but the HTML always loaded fine. Its that the animations aren't performing. The animations are controlled by Skrollr library and its producing an error on iframe load.